# Installing GitLab 6.7 on Ubuntu 12.04 server, for a gitlab recovery

Tags: redis, ubuntu-12.04, gitlab

Hi I'm trying to install gitlab 6.7 to recover from a crash I had on the program. I cannot find an instruction set to follow and I keep running into errors when reading the [git 8-0-stable instruction set](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md). 
The error I'm running into now is

2015-09-21T19:26:06Z 10281 TID-orcy1dxco INFO: Sidekiq client with redis options {:url=> "http://IP", :namespace=>"resque:gitlab"}
rake aborted!
Error connecting to Redis on [IP] (ENCONNREFUSED)

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate for serverfault http://serverfault.com/

Comment: If you are looking for the 'install' instruction set for GitLab 6.7, you can find it here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/v6.7.5/doc/install/installation.md for a source install, or here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/6.7.5.omnibus/README.md for an omnibus install

Comment: Thanks soo much! The install actually worked. Thanks  [twk3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3965391/twk3)